# Drupal 7 - Display a Block in shadowbox?

Tags: drupal-7, shadowbox

How to display a block in shadow box?

I have used this

```
<a href="node_popup/15" rel="shadowbox;height=600;width=800;">My link</a>
```

when i click this it is not displaying in shadow box....

What is the problem

Answer (score 0):

If the anchor is following the `href` content, which then implies Shadowbox was ignored, then the problem is either Shadowbox is not installed correctly or initialized via `Shadowbox.init();` in the Head Section.

If all you see is the **dimming background**, then either the correct Shadowbox Player is not installed or the content is not at the specified **href location**.